# How to remove groups from a folder view

Tags: c++, winapi, view, directory

Let's say the current Explorer folder view is grouped, and you want to remove the grouping.  Is there a way to do that?  `IFolderView2::SetGroupBy` doesn't accept a `NULL` or anything like that.  I'm not sure if I'm overlooking some method or interface. Thank you for any help.

Comment: Did you try passing `PKEY_Null` ?

Comment: Nice, that worked.  Thanks a lot.  If you want to make that an answer, I'll accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can call `IFolderView2::SetGroupBy()` with `PKEY_Null` to turn grouping off.